# Remove special characters with doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I do a search to find a city in my database, when I type "Aulnay-sous-bois" no problem I can find the city in question but when I type "Aulnay sous bois" it does not work not !

I already tried to remove the characters but it does not work

my code controller :

```
public function verifyCity(Request $request, CityRepository $cityRepository): JsonResponse
    {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $data = [];
            $searchs = $cityRepository->findBySearchCity($request->request->get('city'));
            /**
             * @var $searchs City[]
             */
            foreach ($searchs as $search) {
                $data[] = [
                    'name' => $search->getName(),
                    'zipCode' => $search->getZipCode()
                ];
            }

            return new JsonResponse(['city' => $data, 'ok' => 1]);
        }
        return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'not found']);
    }
```

my repository

```
public function findBySearchCity($search,$zipCode = null)
    { //SELECT * FROM `city` WHERE name LIKE "%la courn%" OR zip_code LIKE "78%"
         $query =$this->createQueryBuilder("c")
            ->where('c.name LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter('search', "%".$search."%");
         if($zipCode != null) {
             $query->orWhere('c.zipCode LIKE :zipCode')
                 ->setParameter('zipCode', $zipCode."%");
         }
         return $query->getQuery()->setMaxResults(5)
             ->getResult();

    }
```

and Js :

```
   var cityTabs = [];
    $('#registration_form_city').keyup(function () {

        var city = this.value;
        var data = {
            city: city,
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#wizardProperty').attr('data-verify-city'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                cityTabs = [];
                if(data.ok == 1) {
                    $.each(data.city,function (k, v) {
                        cityTabs.push(v.name);
                    });
                }
                console.log(cityTabs);
                $( "#registration_form_city" ).autocomplete({
                    source: cityTabs
                });
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    });
```

as explained above when I type exactly with the dashes it works, but when I type without dash it does not work anymore, how to display results while removing the "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting Arleigh answer, this is how the query should be :

```
public function findBySearchCity($search, $zipCode=null) {
    // Can be done in one line with preg_replace()
    // Replace underscore, any white-space and any non-word character with '%'
    $search=preg_replace("/[_\W\s]+/", '%', $search);

    // Always split init from the rest of the query in case you need to use `$qb->expr()`
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder("city");

    if($zipCode !== null) {
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
                $qb->expr()->like("city.name", ":search"),
                $qb->expr()->like("city.zipCode", ":zipCode")))
           ->setParameter('zipCode', $zipCode.'%');
    } else {
        $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like("city.name", ":search"));
    }

    $qb->setParameter('search', '%'.$search.'%')
       ->setMaxResults(5);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

It should works like that.
If it doesn't, dump the query, update your question with it, and comment here.

**Tips :**

- Always use double quote for your query. Doctrine will only accept single quote for string value (single quote is fine for parameters).
- Never use `where()`, always start with `andWhere()` or `orWhere()`
- Avoir to use `andWhere()` and `orWhere()` together. Prefer `expr()` ([read more here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/and-where-or-where))
- Avoid to mix DQL with pseudo-native (`LIKE`, `IN`, etc) SQL. Doctrine will chew you if it read some native SQL it can't use. Use `expr()` instead. If you can't find what you need in `expr()`, it mean you should create a native query.
- Fully name your alias, easier to read afterward.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `$search` parameter value in your repository method to replace dashes and spaces with the `%` wildcard, using `preg_split()` and `implode()`.

```
public function findBySearchCity($search,$zipCode = null)
{ //SELECT * FROM `city` WHERE name LIKE "%la%courn%" OR zip_code LIKE "78%"

    $search = preg_split("/[\s,-]+/", $search);
    $search = implode("%", $search);

     $query =$this->createQueryBuilder("c")
        ->where('c.name LIKE :search')
        ->setParameter('search', "%".$search."%");
     if($zipCode != null) {
         $query->orWhere('c.zipCode LIKE :zipCode')
             ->setParameter('zipCode', $zipCode."%");
     }
     return $query->getQuery()->setMaxResults(5)
         ->getResult();

}
```

So your terms "Aulnay-sous-bois" or "Aulnay sous bois" will both result in a query using:
`... LIKE '%Aulnay%sous%bois%'`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I tried but it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you a different alternative using [MySQL's Full-Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) Functions. Lets begin to prepare the table:

```
ALTER TABLE city ADD FULLTEXT (`name`);
```